# Authentication not authorized

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I'm trying to integrate Google Play Games Services as an update to my already published Android game.
However signin is not working and I get a "SIGN_IN status: ERROR_NOT_AUTHORIZED" error message.

I guess that it may be related to linked app that doesn't have an Oath Client ID for Android. So I tried to created one, but got an error message : "The fingerprint you specified is already used by an Android OAuth2 client ID in this project or another project".
This is true, this SHA fingerprint is indeed used by another game that I already published, as I used the same certificate for both games.

Is it a bad practice to use the same certificate for multiple apps ?
What should I do to link my app, as I guess I can't change the certificate on any of the two games as they are already published ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

> The fingerprint you specified is already used by an Android OAuth2
>   client ID in this project or another project

implies that you shouldn't be doing that, so to me it doesn't sound like a good practice.

Try to generate a different signed certificate for each project.

Comment: Sound like that to me as well. But as both apps are already published, what can I do ?

Comment: But if I create a new one I'll have to use another bundle ID and current users of the app won't get an the update

Comment: Best I found is to unpublish an app on Games Services, and recreate another one.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to Unpublish in Google Play Games services. Given that you're the owner of the app, I was expecting that you'd know these things especially if you're the one who uploaded it.